# Vb.net export data to excel

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2013, windows-forms-designer

I have a problem with the following code to export the data to excel with following button click Event:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    ExportToExcel()
End Sub
```

**here is the code**

```
Private Sub ExportToExcel()
    Dim ExcelApp As Object, ExcelBook As Object
    Dim ExcelSheet As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Try
        Me.DgView.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Navy
        Me.DgView.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
        Me.DgView.GridColor = Color.Blue
        Me.DgView.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
        Me.DgView.RowHeadersBorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D


        DgView.AutoGenerateColumns = False

        Dim ReferColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        ReferColumn.DataPropertyName = "Refer_no"
        ReferColumn.HeaderText = "ካሴት መ/ቁ"
        ReferColumn.Width = 80

        Dim TitleColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        TitleColumn.DataPropertyName = "Title"
        TitleColumn.HeaderText = "ካሴት ርእስ"
        TitleColumn.Width = 150

        Dim GnrNmColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        GnrNmColumn.DataPropertyName = "Genre_Name"
        GnrNmColumn.HeaderText = "የካሴት ዓይነት"
        GnrNmColumn.Width = 100

        Dim GrpNmColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        GrpNmColumn.DataPropertyName = "Group_Name"
        GrpNmColumn.HeaderText = "የምድብ ስም"
        GrpNmColumn.Width = 100

        Dim ActColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        ActColumn.DataPropertyName = "Actors"
        ActColumn.HeaderText = "ሪፖርተር"
        ActColumn.Width = 150

        Dim DirecColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        DirecColumn.DataPropertyName = "Director"
        DirecColumn.HeaderText = "ኃላፊ"
        DirecColumn.Width = 150

        Dim LangColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        LangColumn.DataPropertyName = "Language"
        LangColumn.HeaderText = "ቋንቋ"
        LangColumn.Width = 150
        Dim releasedateColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        LangColumn.DataPropertyName = "release_date"
        LangColumn.HeaderText = "የተቀረፀበተት ቀነን"
        LangColumn.Width = 150
        Dim StatusColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        StatusColumn.DataPropertyName = "status"
        StatusColumn.HeaderText = "ሁኔታ"
        StatusColumn.Width = 80

        Dim synopsisColumn As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        synopsisColumn.DataPropertyName = "synopsis"
        synopsisColumn.HeaderText = "የተቀረፀበተት ጉዳይ"
        synopsisColumn.Width = 180

        DgView.Columns.Add(ReferColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(TitleColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(GnrNmColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(GrpNmColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(ActColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(DirecColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(LangColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(releasedateColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(StatusColumn)
        DgView.Columns.Add(synopsisColumn)

        Dim columns As String() = {"Refer_No", "Title", "genre_name", "group_name", "Actors", "Director", "Language", "release_date", "Status", "synopsis"}


        DVDModule.FillListWithoutParam(DVDList, columns, "usp_SelectDVDList", _
                                                         GetType(Entity.DVD))

        FormatGridWithBothTableAndColumnStyles()
        DgView.DataSource = DVDList


        'create object of excel
        ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        ExcelBook = ExcelApp.WorkBooks.Add
        ExcelSheet = ExcelBook.WorkSheets(1)

        With ExcelSheet
            For Each column As DataGridViewColumn In DgView.Columns
                .cells(1, column.Index + 1) = column.HeaderText
            Next
            For i = 1 To Me.DgView.RowCount
                .cells(i + 1, 1) = Me.DgView.Rows(i - 1).Cells("Refer_no").Value
                For j = 1 To DgView.Columns.Count - 1
                    .cells(i + 1, j + 1) = DgView.Rows(i - 1).Cells(j).Value
                Next
            Next
        End With

        ExcelApp.Visible = True
        '
        ExcelSheet = Nothing
        ExcelBook = Nothing
        ExcelApp = Nothing
```

Comment: please format your code. nobody can read this mess

Comment: I fix it it was path write permission problem

Answer (score 0):

I admit I didn't read all of your code. It's a mess and there's too much code for your question. It gives you some kind of error or what?

Anyway, if you just want to export a table showing some data, I suggest you to create a `.csv` file instead of using MS Excel. It's much more easier to code, faster during execution, and the output file is portable

Comment: Thanks for your info but what I faced is when I run the program and click the button it shows Microsoft excel can't access  the file 'C:\users\7BFEE40' error message and suggests the cause of the error as  the file name or the path doesn't exist or the file is being used by other program or the work book you are trying to save hase the same name as the currently opend